# Quantitative Ramsey theorem - asymmetric and multicolors

Tags: reference-request, ramsey-theory

Let $q\geq 1$ and $H_1,\dots, H_q$ be graphs.

By Ramsey theorem, it is well-known that there exists $n_0$ such that the following holds.

> If $n\geq n_0$ and the edges of $K_n$ are colored with $q$ colors, then there exists an $i\in\{1,\ldots,q\}$ such that there exists a monochromatic copy of $H_i$ in color $i$.

The following quantitative version also holds.

> There exist positive constants $c>0$ and $n_0$ such that, if $n\geq n_0$ and the edges of $K_n$ are colored with $q$ colors, then there exists an $i\in\{1,\ldots,q\}$ such that there are at least $c n^{|V(H_i)|}$ monochromatic copies of $H_i$ in color $i$.

It is often quoted as "Folklore", and I know it is not too difficult to prove. I've found some related theorem (often related to Ramsey-multiplicities, e.g, [this article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jgt.3190040403) by Burr and Rosta), but not covering the multicolor / asymmetric case. For completeness, I would like to insert an actual reference in an article.

Comment: This immediately follows from the usual Ramsey theorem by averaging over subsets of size $N$=Ramsey number. So most probably it was not published as a separate result, and many people got it independently.

Comment: @FedorPetrov yep that's my guess. I know the proof, I could write a summary of it. I was just hoping for some reference. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that the exponent you have for the lower bound here is quite correct, especially for some sparse H's like stars. Guess I have to sit down and write out some details, both for the standard averaging/probabilistic argument and what happens for stars. Did you ever find an explicit published proof or discussion of this Thomas?

Comment: Hi Mike, you can find the proof written in this paper by Nenadov and Steger, https://as.inf.ethz.ch/people/members/rnenadov/papers/random_ramsey.pdf,
Theorem 2. It's for the symmetric case $H_1=\ldots=H_q$, but the asymmetric is just an easy generalization.